# Why some functions from imported module don't require class like dot notation for calling them, when "import as" notation is used?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

There are two ways of importing anything from a module. One way is by using:
`from array import *`
This way, functions/classes can directly be accessed from the module, for instance, here:

```
from array import *       

arr = array('i', [1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 6])

print(len(arr)) #This works as expected
```

The another way of import is: `import array as ar` In this case, functions/classes from the module are accessed by dot notation like used with class:

```
import array as ar

arr = ar.array('i', [1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 6]) #The dot notation, ar.array

print(len(arr))  # Why it isn't written as ar.len(arr)
```

In this case, how come `len()` function is directly accessible? Without using dot notation, i.e. `ar.lent()`?

Comment: `len` is a builtin... and nothing to do with `array`... eg: `len('adasdfasdsaf')` will work just as well

Comment: @JonClements How come the inbuilt function is able to determine the `len()` of a custom data structure?

Comment: The object contains a `__len__` method which is what the `len` method calls... and something like `arr[5]` is basically syntax for `arr.__getitem__(5)`... etc... (mind be worth having a read of https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

Comment: (specifically https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__)

Comment: Python itself is pretty dumb. It doesn't know how to add things or even what length is. Python objects have a slew of "magic methods" that let the object decide for itself what something like "add" or "length" means. If you don't implement `__length__` (and nothing you inherit from does), then you get the default object's `__length__` implementation that raises an error. "length" doesn't make sense generally, it should be implemented by classes that do lengthy things.